# Apache tomcat server shows java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, server

In my project I am using `axis.jar(1.4)`.When I start or restart my server it shows the `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException` exception.I have searched over in Internet to resolve the exception,but I couldn't find any solution.So please kindly provide a useful solution to resolve this issue.

**Exception**

```
09:47:56 org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BaseDeserializerFactory - createFactory - DEBUG line 253 - Exception:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.ArrayDeserializerFactory.<init>(java.lang.Class, javax.xml.namespace.QName)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2706)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1657)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.BaseDeserializerFactory.createFactory(BaseDeserializerFactory.java:246)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.deployTypeMapping(WSDDService.java:554)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.initTMR(WSDDService.java:253)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.<init>(WSDDService.java:233)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.<init>(WSDDDeployment.java:192)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.setDocument(WSDDDocument.java:139)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDocument.<init>(WSDDDocument.java:65)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.configureEngine(FileProvider.java:179)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.init(AxisEngine.java:172)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.<init>(AxisEngine.java:156)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.<init>(AxisServer.java:88)
    at org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory.createServer(DefaultAxisServerFactory.java:109)
    at org.apache.axis.server.DefaultAxisServerFactory.getServer(DefaultAxisServerFactory.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.getServer(AxisServer.java:73)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.getEngine(AxisServletBase.java:185)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.getOption(AxisServletBase.java:396)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.init(AxisServletBase.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1284)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1197)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: axis 1.4 is ANCIENT, even by java standards - and i have seen a lot of problems with conflicting jar files that include more modern versions of things ...

Comment: You might be calling method from apis with wrong signature or name. Or the method you are calling may not exist at all in the library.

Comment: Post code for `createFactory` and imports. I think you are passing the parameters to the method incorrectly.

Comment: Classloader is returning an incorrect `ArrayDeserializerFactory` class, Maybe tomcat is loading a different jar at runtime that the one used in compile time or you have the same class in different jars and tomcat is obtaining the wrong one.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-2296, this is not a bug, this is a DEBUG message telling you that the factory cannot be instantiate at first attempt (using reflexion).

Reading Axis code, you will find that there are 2 others tries after this one.